# Python3 mask-string

Tags: python

I am trying to solve an exercise in python3 and I can't get it to work.

I have this code:

```
def mask_string(string3):
    """Mask string"""
    s = string3[-4:].rjust(len(string3), "#")
    masking_string = ""
    string3_length = len(s)
    result = multiply_str(masking_string, string3_length) + s

    return result

def multiply_str(string3, masking_string):
    """Mulitply string"""

    new_multiply_str = string3 * int(masking_string)
    return new_multiply_str
```

And I am running it like this:

```
elif choice == "10":
    string3 = input("Enter a string that will replace all of the caracters with # exept the 4 last ones: ") 
    print(marvin.mask_string(string3)) 
    masking_string = input("Enter number: ") 
    print(marvin.multiply_str(string3, masking_string))
```

And I get this error when I run it:

```
line 131, in multiply_str new_multiply_str = string3 * int(masking_string) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Would really appreciate some help, and please dumb it down a lot when explaining because I am new to python and still do not understand a lot of how to do things.

Comment: seems like `masking_string` is empty string and the error is expected result when you do basically `int("")`

Comment: You have asked about this exact assignment before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481859/mask-string-python. Here and there, you have failed to provide any example of inputs and desired outputs....

Answer (score 1):

```py
line 131, in multiply_str new_multiply_str = string3 * int(masking_string) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Therefore your `masking_string` was "" which is not a valid number (integer or not).  You must have pressed enter without entering a number.

If you want to prevent this, wrap your input routine in a loop and only return when you have a number:

```
def get_int():
    while True:
        x = input("Number: ")
        try:
            return int(x)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Invalid input {x}, try again...")
```